# $scope.$on executing more than once

Tags: angularjs

I am using broadcast and $scope.$on , but the method in $scope.$on executing multiple times.
Here is my code.
In controller:

```
$scope.selectItem = function(index, item){
    BaseService.hideView();
},

$scope.$on("closeView",function(){
    $log.debug("InsideOn: calling hideViewedItem");
    $scope.hideViewedItem();
});
```

In BaseService :

```
app.factory('BaseService', function ($rootScope, $log, $location) {
    return {
       hideView :function(){
        $log.debug("calling closeView");
        $rootScope.$broadcast("closeView", 1);
     }
    }
});
```

Here it is calling hideView once but hideViewedItem calling 3 times. In console I am getting these messages.

```
calling closeview
InsideOn: calling hideViewedItem
InsideOn: calling hideViewedItem
InsideOn: calling hideViewedItem
```

How to make this call only once?

Comment: Why do you have a service doing work on the view?

Comment: I am calling hideView function from other contollers also. two controllers are using the same method. so I keep in a service.

Comment: Is the thing that's being hidden in the View that's being managed by each controller? If not, what is the relationship between the view being managed by the controller and the other view that's being hidden?

Comment: I have 3 views (new item view, messages view, contacts view)new item and mesage view controlled by msgController,contacts view controlled by contactsController. when ever new item view opens and with out close that view,if I click contacts then I am calling hideView,if I click message without closing new item  when item view opened then I am calling hideView.

Comment: Can you please use some punctuation or something in your comment to make it clear what you're talking about. That's really garbled.

Comment: Plus, if you said anything at all about where the view is that is being hidden and what controller is controlling it and what its relationship is to your other controllers, that got lost. Hit: I'm looking for something like the view that's hiding the view is a parent of the views that are calling the service, or a sibling, or something like that.

Comment: In my App, newItem Button, message button, contacts button. By default message shows. when contact button hits contacts info is displayed. when newItem button clicks new message view opens. newmessage view,messages view are controlled by msgController, and contacts view controllered by contactsController. if I click new item button, I have to submit an item or cacel submit then it close the view. if I open new item and clicks contacts button or message button , I am closing the new Item view using this events.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you since you can't answer simple questions that would help me to do that.